# 'int' object is not subscriptable when calling a function from a tkinter button

Tags: python, tkinter

The error occurs once the button has been clicked and the function button_click() and input_validation()  is run. I have tried putting int around the coordinates variables using brackets, in case they were not being treated as integers but that didn't work.

```
import random

from tkinter import *

def button_click():
    def input_validation(coordinates, user_input):

        if coordinates [0] <0 or coordinates [1] <0 and coordinates [0] >2 or coordinates [1] >2:
            pass
        
        elif (user_input == frame.grid_slaves(coordinates[0], coordinates[1])[0]['text']):
            return True
            
            Label (frame, text = frame.grid_slaves(coordinates[0], coordinates[1])[0]['text']
                   ).grid(row= previous_coordinates[0], column= previous_coordinates[1])
            
            Label (frame, text = "").grid(row= coordinates[0], column= coordinates[1])
            

    if (input_validation(coordinates_up, number_input) == True):
        pass

    elif(input_validation(coordinates_left, number_input) == True):
        pass

    elif(input_validation(coordinates_right, number_input) == True):
        pass

    elif(input_validation(coordinates_down, number_input) == True):
        text_display.configure(text="Please input a number that is surrounding the empty space")  


puzzle  = Tk()
puzzle.title("Eight Puzzle")
frame = Frame(puzzle)
space_coordinates = [2,2]
frame.pack()

number_input= Entry(frame, width= 20)
number_input.grid(row = 5, column =7)

button = Button(frame, text="Enter", command = button_click)
button.grid(row = 6, column = 7)
number = 8

text_display = Label(frame, text="Input the number you want to move into the empty space \n *make sure the number is next to the empty space*", fg="red")
text_display.grid(row = 3, column = 7)

for i in range (0,3):
    for a in range (0,3):
        
        if number == 0:
            Label (frame, text = " ").grid(row=i, column=a)
        else:
            Label (frame, text = number).grid(row=i, column=a)
        number= number -1 

previous_coordinates = []
previous_coordinates.append(space_coordinates[0])
previous_coordinates.append(space_coordinates[1])
coordinates_up = previous_coordinates[1]-1
coordinates_left = previous_coordinates[0]-1
coordinates_right = previous_coordinates[0]+1
coordinates_down = previous_coordinates[1]+1
```

Comment: somewhere you are considering an `int` as a list, that is what  this error is!

Comment: `coordinates [0]` remove `[]` it doesn't work because `coordinates_up = previous_coordinates[1]-1` <- here you have assigned coordinates_up an int similarity others(coordinates_left, ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a single coordinate as the first argument to `input_validation` but you are trying to treat it like a list inside the function.

The solution is either to pass a list of coordinates into `input_validation`, or rewrite the function so that it properly treats `coordinates` as an int.